# Issue with case statement inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I am writting and update to my database, which i want to import but i do not know what is wrong with my code. MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin return me a syntax error. It is just an example case statement. Can anyone help me?

```
SET @company_code = 0;
SELECT @company_code := LOWER(`value`) FROM `settings` WHERE `setting_name` = 'COMPANY_CODE';
CREATE PROCEDURE p(in  code varchar(200))
BEGIN 
CASE code  
    WHEN 'first_company' THEN SELECT code;
    ELSE SELECT '1';
END CASE
END;

CALL p(@company_code);
```

Can i do that without creating the procedure?

Comment: Can you please tell us what you want to achieve exactly? 
Which result you are expecting?

Comment: In my code Select will be replaced by insert statement. I want add new records to few databeses only if the company_code in the databese will be xyz.

Comment: What I understand here is if "settings" table has the record with company_code = "first_company" then you want to insert the record, Am I right?

Comment: Yes, then i want to add the new record to another table.

Comment: No need of a procedure if you want to do it once.

Comment: I don't think you can without a procedure since you seem to want to insert to multiple databases since that implies a loop which can only occur in a stored program,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing a semi-colon after `END`
2. You need to use a delimiter other than `;` in order to create procedure

See [Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) for explanation.

```sql
DELIMITER foo

CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN code VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
  CASE code
    WHEN 'first_company' THEN INSERT INTO dest_first SELECT code, * FROM srctable;
    ELSE                      INSERT INTO dest_other SELECT '1',  * FROM srctable;
  END CASE;
END;
foo

DELIMITER ;

SET @company_code = 0;
SELECT @company_code := LOWER(value) FROM settings WHERE setting_name = 'COMPANY_CODE';
CALL p(@company_code);
```

Comment: In original query i want to replace select with insert to, so it will not work with it.

Comment: You _need_ a stored procedure. You cannot select a table dynamically inside simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion above, If "settings" table has the record with company_code = "first_company" then you want to insert the record then it can be achieved by this way

```
INSERT INTO colourmst (CODE, Column1) 
SELECT LOWER(`value`) , 'XYZ'
FROM `settings` WHERE `setting_name` = 'COMPANY_CODE'
```

Comment: it's not exactly what you want to achieve. I want to write 1 udpading file, which i am going to import to few databases with differrent copmany codes. If company code will be 'xyz' the insert something to 'xyz1' table, if company code will be 'xyzz' then insert something else to 'xyz1' table.